# A 8086 assembly hexdump program

Tags: assembly

I am trying to learn the 8086 assembly language.  So as exercise, I decided to write a hexdump program, that outputs the contents of files in a format similar to Linux hexdump.

I am developing under Concurrent CP/M 86 inside an emulator.

My version of hexdump reads a file name from command line and print the contents on the console.  I don't have any experience with the assembly language, so I'm trying to find ways to improve.  I still don't know how to structure code and name labels and variables.

```
ccpmint equ 224
p_termcpm equ 0
c_read equ 1
c_write equ 2
c_writestr equ 9
f_open equ 15
f_close equ 16
f_read equ 20
f_dmaoff equ 26

cseg

start:

    ; copy filename to fcb
    mov cx, 0
    mov di, offset fcb
    mov si, 05ch
fcbloop:
    cmp cx, 16
    jz  fcbend
    mov dl, [si]
    mov [di], dl
    inc si
    inc di
    inc cx
    jmp fcbloop
fcbend:

    ; set current dma to dma in dseg
    mov cl, f_dmaoff
    mov dx, offset dma
    call ccpm

    ; open the file
    mov cl, f_open
    mov dx, offset fcb
    call ccpm
    cmp al, 0
    jnz error

    ; read the file
    mov readcnt, 0
read_loop:
    mov cl, f_read
    mov dx, offset fcb
    call ccpm
    cmp al, 0
    jnz read_end

    mov ax, readcnt
    inc ax
    mov readcnt, ax
    mov cl, c_writestr
    mov dx, offset crlf
    call ccpm
    call print_dma
    mov cl, c_read
    call ccpm
    jmp read_loop
read_end:
    cmp al, 01h
    jnz error

    ; close the file
    mov cl, f_close
    mov dx, offset fcb
    call ccpm
    cmp al, 0
    jnz error

terminate:
    ; terminate the program
    mov cl, p_termcpm
    mov dx, 0
    call ccpm

error:
    ; error handling
    mov tmp, ax
    mov cl, c_writestr
    mov dx, offset errmsg
    int ccpmint
    mov al, last_cl
    call print_byte
    mov cl, c_writestr
    mov dx, offset erral
    int ccpmint
    mov ax, tmp
    call print_byte
    mov cl, c_writestr
    mov dx, offset errah
    int ccpmint
    mov ax, tmp
    mov al, ah
    call print_byte
    mov cl, c_writestr
    mov dx, offset crlf
    int ccpmint
    jmp terminate

print_dma:
    ; fill lines of 16 bytes and prints each line
    mov cx, 0
    mov si, offset dma
    mov di, offset buf
pdmaloop:
    mov ax, [si]
    mov [di], ax
    inc cx
    inc si
    inc di
    mov ax, 0fh
    and ax, cx
    jnz pdmaloop
    call print_line
    cmp cx, 128
    jz pdmaend
    mov di, offset buf
    jmp pdma_loop
pdmaend:
    ret


print_line:
    ; prints a single dma line: address, bytes, chars
    ; address = readcnt*128 + cx
    push cx
    mov dx, cx
    mov ax, readcnt
    mov cl, 7
    shl ax, cl
    add ax, dx
    call print_word
    mov cl, c_write
    mov dl, 32
    call ccpm

    ; print bytes
    mov di, offset buf
    mov cx, 0
plbloop:
    mov tmp, cx
    mov al, [di]
    call print_byte
    mov cl, c_write
    mov dl, 32
    call ccpm
    mov cx, tmp
    inc cx
    inc di
    cmp cx, 16
    jnz plbloop

    ; print chars
    mov di, offset buf
    mov cx, 0
plcloop:
    mov tmp, cx
    mov al, [di]
    cmp al, 32
    jb plcpdot
    cmp al, 126
    jbe plcpchr
plcpdot:
    mov al, '.'
plcpchr:
    mov cl, c_write
    mov dl, al
    call ccpm
    mov cx, tmp
    inc di
    inc cx
    cmp cx, 16
    jb plcloop

    ; write crlf and return
    mov cl, c_writestr
    mov dx, offset crlf
    call ccpm
    pop cx
    ret

print_word:
    ; prints a word: the highest byte, then the lowest
    push ax
    mov al, ah
    call print_byte
    pop ax
    call print_byte
    ret

print_byte:
    ; prints the two characters of a byte in al
    push ax
    and al, 0f0h
    mov cl, 4
    shr al, cl
    call print_nibble
    pop ax
    and al, 0fh
    call print_nibble
    ret

print_nibble:
    ; prints a single hexadecimal digit
    cmp al, 9
    jg pnib_af
    add al, '0'
    jmp pnib_w
pnib_af:
    add al, 'A'-10
pnib_w:
    mov cl, c_write
    mov dl, al
    int ccpmint
    ret

ccpm:
    mov last_cl, cl
    int ccpmint
    ret

dseg
org 100h

errmsg  db  'error: function=$'
erral   db  ', al=$'
errah   db  ', ah=$'
crlf    db  10,13,'$'
fcb rs  33
dma rs  180
buf rs  16
tmp rw  1
readcnt rw  1
last_cl db  0
end
```

This is how it's compiled:
[image]

And here is what it looks like when executed:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Concurrent CP/M 86 but I do know my 8086.

```
...
dseg
org 100h
...
```

I found it remarkable to see the `org 100h` directive so far down in your program. I would have expected this almost at the first source line!

> I still don't know how to structure code and name labels and variables.

Apart from my remark about `ORG` these are actually quite good.
You used descriptive names and there's a good ordering of the subroutines.

---

> ```
> mov dx, 0
> ```

Each time you clear a register (any general purpose register!), you can do this more efficiently by `XOR` ing the register with itself.

```
xor dx, dx    ;Will set DX=0
```

---

> ```
>    ; copy filename to fcb
>     mov cx, 0
>     mov di, offset fcb
>     mov si, 05ch
> fcbloop:
>     cmp cx, 16
>     jz  fcbend
>     mov dl, [si]
>     mov [di], dl
>     inc si
>     inc di
>     inc cx
>     jmp fcbloop
> fcbend:
> ```

The part where you copy the filename can be much improved by using the `movs` string primitive instruction. You load the desired amount in `CX` and then repeat (`rep`) the operation. The direction flag (DF) is cleared beforehand to force the CPU updating the `SI` and `DI` registers moving up in memory.

```
; copy filename to fcb
mov cx, 16
mov di, offset fcb
mov si, 05ch
cld
rep movsb
```

---

> ```
> mov ax, readcnt
> inc ax
> mov readcnt, ax
> ```

Incrementing the variable *readcnt* can be done in a single instruction:

```
inc readcnt
```

---

> ```
> print_dma:
>     ; fill lines of 16 bytes and prints each line
>     mov cx, 0
>     mov si, offset dma
>     mov di, offset buf
> pdmaloop:
>     mov ax, [si]
>     mov [di], ax
>     inc cx
>     inc si
>     inc di
>     mov ax, 0fh
>     and ax, cx
>     jnz pdmaloop
>     call print_line
>     cmp cx, 128
>     jz pdmaend
>     mov di, offset buf
>     jmp pdma_loop
> pdmaend:
>     ret
> ```

This procedure must process **bytes** (you raise the addresses by 1), but you read and write **words**!
The test to see if 16 bytes were processed is too complicated. All that is needed is testing `CX` with 15.

```
print_dma:
    ; fill lines of 16 bytes and prints each line
    xor cx, cx
    mov si, offset dma
pdmaloop_:
    mov di, offset buf
pdmaloop:
    movsb
    inc cx
    test cx, 15
    jnz pdmaloop
    call print_line
    cmp cx, 128
    jne pdma_loop_
    ret
```

See how I reduced the number of instructions by introducing an extra label on top and no longer needing the label at the bottom?

---

> ```
> print_word:
>     ; prints a word: the highest byte, then the lowest
>     push ax
>     mov al, ah
>     call print_byte
>     pop ax
>     call print_byte
>     ret
> print_byte:
> ```

A `call` directly above a `ret` can safely be replaced by a `jmp`.
But since the target immediately follows, you can just not write the `jmp`.

```
print_word:
    ; prints a word: the highest byte, then the lowest
    push ax
    mov al, ah
    call print_byte
    pop ax
print_byte:
```

---

> ```
>     call print_nibble
>     pop ax
>     and al, 0fh
>     call print_nibble
>     ret
> print_nibble:
> ```

Similarly this snippet becomes:

```
    call print_nibble
    pop ax
    and al, 0fh
print_nibble:
```

---

> ```
>     cmp al, 9
>     jg pnib_af
>     add al, '0'
>     jmp pnib_w
> pnib_af:
>     add al, 'A'-10
> pnib_w:
> ```

A simpler way of converting follows. It uses less labels which is a good thing for readability. It uses less jumps which is a good thing for speed.

```
    cmp al, 10
    jb  pnib_
    add al, 7      ;7 is ('A' - 10) - '0'
pnib_:
    add al, '0'
```

Comment: That `org 100h` is within the data segment.  All the stuff before it is in the code segment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me.  The `org 100h` in `dseg` is because in Concurrent CP/M-86 the small memory model uses the first 256 bytes of the data segment for the base page (this is where I copy the file name given as argument from).  When the `org 100h` is in `cseg`, it's called the 8080 memory model in the Concurrent CP/M documentation.

Comment: Here is the [improved version](https://pastebin.com/2mPMjCWa), in case someone would want to test my code, with some bugs corrected and behaviour improved (the user can press q to quit and there is no pause after last screen).

Comment: @andrei Indeed a much improved version! Nice to see that you corrected a few errors that I had overlooked (like those addresses that were out of sync). Concerning the addition of the user response: Allowing the user to quit is a nice feature, but I think it would be best to not jump to the *Terminate* label but rather to the *CloseFile* code directly above it.

Comment: @andrei You could consider posting your improved version as a follow up question on this forum. There's more advice that can be offered...